# Convert between byte count and "human-readable" string

Tags: shell

Is there a shell command that simply converts back and forth between a number string in bytes  and the "human-readable" number string offered by some commands via the `-h` option?

To clarify the question: `ls -l` without the `-h` option (some output supressed)

```
> ls -l 
  163564736 file1.bin
      13209 file2.bin
```

gives the size in bytes, while with the `-h`option (some output supressed)

```
> ls -lh 
  156M file1.bin
   13K file2.bin
```

the size is human readable in kilobytes and megabytes.

Is there a shell command that simply turns `163564736`into `156M` and `13209` into `13K` and also does the reverse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File size in human readable format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854332/file-size-in-human-readable-format)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[numfmt](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html)

To:

```
echo "163564736" | numfmt --to=iec
```

From:

```
echo "156M" | numfmt --from=iec
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. For the reverse it is `echo "156M" | numfmt --from=iec`. Do want to add that to the answer?

Comment: Note, the pipe is not required, the `numfmt` also supports `numfmt --to=iec 163564736` and `numfmt --from=iec 156M`...

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard (cross-platform) tool to do it. But solution using `awk` is [described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/a-standard-tool-to-convert-a-byte-count-into-human-kib-mib-etc-like-du-ls1)

Comment: I guess [numfmt](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html), suggested in another answer, is cross-platform in the linux world?

Comment: @Svaberg Sure it is! If you follow POSIX and a bunch of other rules, your shell scripts can be the most portable software ever created: they will work properly on any Linux, FreeBSD, UNIX, MAC, Android...

Comment: I see. So when, in your answer, you say that "there is no standard (cross-platform) tool", do you mean that numfmt is not standard?

Comment: @Svaberg Yes, precisely. `numfmt` is part of GNU coreutils from 2013, but `awk` in contrast is essential part of classic UNIX shell since 1970s, standardized by POSIX since 1990s, and likely lives even inside your mobile phone...

Comment: ...if only I could use awk on my iPhone :D